# Unable to download files with wget

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

**[SOLVED] by copy dataset from pendrive to VM machine**  
I wanted to download a csv file from data.world Link: https://query.data.world/s/ivhtuhwlmurugide54rarbhjr6tyfq using Linux on my Virtual Machine. i run the following command but it does not work. Tried parameters like no check cert as well, still wont work.

```
wget https://query.data.world/s/ivhtuhwlmurugide54rarbhjr6tyfq
```

Error I get:

```
Unable to establish SSL connection
```

Comment: Your command is correct and it works for me ,are you trying this command from virtual machine? what is the version of wget you are using? probably your get version is too old to support website SSL certificate, upgrade it

Comment: @JatinMehrotra yes the command is run from a VM provided from my university for big data subject. 
This is the output I get for command "rpm -qa | grep wget" 
wget - 1.12-1.4.el6.x86_64

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. The only reason for such an error, from wget perspective anyways, is that it wasn't compiled with the necessary SSL library.

It'd be helpful to include all pertaining output of the command, and perhaps provide `wget -V` out as well.

Comment: @Mers this is the output for wget -v, but i have found alternative solution for my problem. thank you
`GNU Wget 1.12 built on linux-gnu.
+digest +ipv6 +nls +ntlm +opie +md5/openssl +https -gnutls +openssl 
-iri 

Wgetrc: 
    /etc/wgetrc (system)
Locale: /usr/share/locale`

Comment: `Compile: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/etc/wgetrc" 
    -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/share/locale" -I. -I../lib -O2 -g -pipe -Wall 
    -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector 
    --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic 
Link: gcc -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions 
    -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic 
    -L/usr/lib6464 -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lz /usr/lib64/libssl.so 
    /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so -ldl -lrt ftp-opie.o openssl.o http-ntlm.o 
    gen-md5.o ../lib/libgnu.a `

Comment: I am glad you figured it out, @JhurngChew!

Answer (score -2):

did you install wget on your server ?

try with this command-> sudo apt install wget

Comment: Enable SSL site on your server.

a2ensite default-ssl
systemctl restart apache2

Comment: Please share more details. If `wget` wasn't installed in the first place, how should running that command yield the given error message?

Comment: If `wget` was not on the machine, the error message would be different.